# Use spherical coordinates to find the volume of a solid.

Tags: calculus

> To Find:Use spherical coordinates to find the volume of the solid within the cone

$$\phi =\frac{\pi}{4}$$

> and between the spheres
>   $$\rho =1,\rho =2$$
>   now we have
>   $$R=\left \{ (\rho ,\theta ,\phi ):1 \le\rho  \le 2,0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{4},0 \le \theta \le 2\pi \right \}$$
>   and the volume is:
>   $$V= \int_1^2\int_0^\frac
> {\pi}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\rho ^2\sin \phi \,d\theta\,d\phi \,d\rho  $$
>
> But where to from here?

$$\int_1^2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}{}2\pi \rho^2 \sin \phi \,d\phi \,d\rho $$

$$=\int_1^2(1-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{2}})2\pi\rho^2 \,d\rho $$

$$=\left.(1-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{2}})2\pi\frac{\rho^3}{3}\right|_1^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good up to the second last line, the antiderivative of $\rho^2$ should be $\frac {\rho^3}{3}$ so you would get: $$2\pi(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})\int_1^2\rho^2d\rho=2\pi(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})(\frac{2^3}{3}-\frac{1^3}{3})=\frac{14\pi}{3}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$$

Comment: I just noticed that you edited it, the last line is correct. Just evaluate $\rho$ at the upper and lower bounds!